# Difficulty implementing code 128 C rule

Tags: c++, qt, barcode, barcode-printing, escpos

Code related to text encoding:

```
const char* toCode128C( const char* texto ) {

    int tamanhoTexto = strlen( texto );
    int tamanhoComando = strlen( "{C" ) + tamanhoTexto;

    char* printerCodBarras = new char[ tamanhoComando ];
    memcpy( printerCodBarras, "{C", tamanhoComando );

    for ( int i = 0; i < tamanhoTexto; i += 2 )  {
        int num = QString( texto ).mid( i, 2 ).toInt();
        QString vl = QString( static_cast<char>( num ) );

        strncat( printerCodBarras, vl.toStdString().c_str(), 1 );
    }

    return printerCodBarras;

}
```

Encoding occurs successfully, except when it contains a "00" for example code 59900001, the transformation occurs from two characters to two characters, or error occurs when encoding the value "00", thus making the (00) is not printed.

Comment: Why are you using `char` arrays instead of `std::string`?

Comment: You didn't add an extra byte for the null terminator in C-style strings.

Comment: What is the incorrect encoding that you're getting from `00`?

Comment: You turn `00` into a single zero byte aka NUL aka `'\0'`. `strncat` treats it as a string terminator.

Comment: `char* printerCodBarras = new char[ tamanhoComando ];` -- Hopefully the caller figures out to `delete[]` this memory.  Better just to use `std::string` and not have memory-leak issues.

Comment: I will make the adjustments as you said, this part of the conversion to \ 00 and the char * understand how null it makes sense, I will check (I will use std :: string also to test, thanks already)

Comment: So, after encoding the text that I need to send to print, the method that writes the data uses const char*, ie even though I work with std::string when sending the same to the method, it will be lost, so the problem is actually at 00 which is understood as terminator NULL :/